# SQL: How to make multiple joins to the same column of a table without overriding results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of basketball matches and a table of basketball teams like this:

```
MATCHES:
ID   |   HOME_TEAM_ID  |  AWAY_TEAM_ID | SCORE_HOME | SCORE_AWAY
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    |       20        |       21      |     80     |    110
2    |       12        |       10      |     96     |     90


TEAMS:
ID   |   NAME
-------------------------
20   |   BULLS
21   |   KNICKS
```

Given a match ID, I would like to retrieve both the score and the team names. How do I make a JOIN that retrieves both team names from the teams table?

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM matches AS m
JOIN teams AS t1 ON t.id = m.home_team_id
JOIN teams AS t2 ON ti.id = m.away_team_id
WHERE m.id = 1
```

...but here the result from the second JOIN statement seems to override the one from the first, so I only get one name:

```
[id] => 1
[score_home] => 80
[score_away] => 110
[name] => KNICKS
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM matches AS m
JOIN teams AS t ON (t.id = m.home_team_id OR t.id = m.away_team_id)
WHERE m.id = 1
```

...which returns two results :

```
[id] => 1
[score_home] => 80
[score_away] => 110
[name] => BULLS
```

and

```
[id] => 1
[score_home] => 80
[score_away] => 110
[name] => KNICKS
```

I would like to make a query that returns something like this

```
[id] => 1
[score_home] => 80
[score_away] => 110
[name_home_team] => BULLS
[name_home_team] => KNICKS
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Matches.ID,
    Matches.Score_Home,
    Matches.Score_Away,
    HomeTeam.Name Home_Team_Name,
    AwayTeam.Name Away_Team_Name
FROM
    Matches
    INNER JOIN Teams HomeTeam ON Matches.Home_Team_ID = HomeTeam.ID
    INNER JOIN Teams AwayTeam ON Matches.Away_Team_ID = AwayTeam.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   select  m.ID,
           (select NAME from TEAM where id=m.HOME_TEAM_ID) HOME_TEAM_NAME,
           m.SCORE_HOME,
           (select NAME from TEAM where id=m.AWAY_TEAM_ID) AWAY_TEAM_NAME,    
           m.SCORE_AWAY 
    from 
    MATCHES m
    where m.ID=1
```

Comment: This one is faster than the join query

Answer (score 2):

you just have to name the column name with alias names

```
SELECT m.ID,
       m.SCORE_HOME,
       m.SCORE_AWAY,
       t1.NAME as name_home_team,
       t2.NAME as name_home_team
FROM MATCHES AS m
JOIN teams AS t1 ON t1.id = m.home_team_id
JOIN teams AS t2 ON t2.id = m.away_team_id
WHERE m.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, should work:

```
select x.id, x.score_home, x.score_away, y.name as home_team, z.name as away_team
from matches x,
  (select name from teams where id = x.home_team_id)y,
  (select name from teams where id = x.away_team_id)z
where x.id = 1;
```